# DateTime index not used during update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have an SQL Server 2008 R2 database which has a table with a number of columns.  One of these columns in a DateTime field (which isn't the primary key).

I am running an Update statement, and the field used in the where clause is this datetime column.

The problem is that although i have a non clustered index on this datetime field, it doesn't seem to be used and performance is slow.  i typically have thousands of these statements to execute consecutively, and i suspect that this date field the issue.

Any ideas how I can address this?

Comment: How **selective** is that `DateTime` column, e.g. how many rows will it select from your table of how many rows in total?? Also: the update will need to go to the underlying data pages anyway, if column values need to be updated - so it cannot just use the index alone anyway...

Comment: "i typically have thousands of these statements to execute consecutively" - that sounds like a bigger problem - is there a reason they can't be written as a single statement to let SQL Server optimize it as a single set-based update?

Comment: unfortunately they cant be combined since in between there are some other statements that need to run, and these are not the same each time either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MS SQL Management Studio to display the execution plan of your query!
You'll see wether the index is used or not!